# Local database and GitHub -- How do I check in?

Tags: database, visual-studio, github

I have a personal project I'm working on. I want to be able to go back and forth between my desktop and laptop via GitHub. The problem is, I can't figure out how to check in my "local" database in Visual Studio. It's the one that would usually show up under SQL Server Object Explorer.

So how can I check that in? I've got the rest of the project checked in, I just need to check in the database.

So how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using the new GitHub features built-into Visual Studio is using the add-on?  GitHub makes opening a repository in VS extremely easy

Comment: I've already got a GitHub repository set up for the project (through Visual Studio). What I'm trying to do is check in the database associated with the project.

Comment: Should just be as simple as performing the commit

Comment: I actually did try that. For some reason, it was unsuccessful. The main solution itself I can check in (two projects, the main project and a test project for unit tests), but the database didn't check in. The database is under the SQL Server Data Objects. If you're using VS2017 or 2019, it's the pop-out on the left side. Trying to check that in.